# Specific view field display names

Tags: c#, sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, vsewss

I've got to create a standard view but I want to display column names different than originals. For example, this view will include the "ID" field, but I need to show its column header like "Order number".
As far as I know Sharepoint doesn't let you choose the display name of a field for a specific view...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe create calculated columsn that do nothing but display the content of the original field for each of the fields you want "translated", then include those in the new view?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But there were a few things that made me choose another solution. When I copy the "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" column I lose the link and the edit menu. Also when I copy the workflow status column it shows numbers instead of the status string.
Since I'm showing this view within a web part (a kind of list view container) I ended up replacing column names using SPView.RenderAsHtml Method!